# How do you configure Apache 2 on Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, configuration

I’m looking to run a Debian VPS as a web server. I’ve got Debian 6 installed, and I’ve got the default Apache 2 installation on there.

I’ve read a bit about how Apache 2 configuration is arranged slightly differently on Debian, and I just wanted to check I understand how Debian expects me to make my configuration changes to Apache.

My understanding is:

#### To add modules:

- Install the module using `apt-get`
- Enable the module using `a2enmod`

#### To add Virtual Hosts:

- Create a separate configuration file for each virtual host (preferably named similarly to the virtual host’s intended domain name) in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`
- Enable the site using the `a2ensite` command

#### To do anything else:

- Create a separate configuration file for each configuration task in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`. All files in this directory are included by default.

I’m basing this on http://www.control-escape.com/web/configuring-apache2-debian.html, and `/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz`.

Am I understanding this correctly? I’m guessing that editing e.g. apache2.conf directly isn’t a good way to add my own configuration settings, as my changes could be blitzed by an update in the future?

Comment: Not a real question? No comments or edits to suggest how it might be improved? Cheers, very friendly.

Comment: if you were to edit apache2.conf, your changes would not be 'blitzed on update' since, because the apache2.2-common declares apache2.conf as a conffile, dpkg would preserve your changes upon upgrade.  However, httpd.conf is a better place to override stuff from apache2.conf so that apche2.conf can be 'blitzed' in the future.

Comment: @stew: ah, gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's right. Completely right.

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct to me. The website you reference seems accurate for the Debian configuration environment.